# can't remove "permission denied" file - even with "sudo" and proper user/group set

Tags: sudo, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, permission-denied

I couldn't delete a file even I change its mode, its user, group properties to proper ones, and even I tried sudo it. I keep receiving "permission denied". Looked online and this forum to no avail.

This happened in a Ubuntu v.18.04 subsystem for Windows. (WSL).

can you help?

```
jon@competition:~/projects/medium-blog-kafka-udemy/udemy-reviews-producer/target/classes/avro$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-rw- 0 jon jon 1320 Oct 11 12:28 udemy-review.avsc
jon@competition:~/projects/medium-blog-kafka-udemy/udemy-reviews-producer/target/classes/avro$ sudo rm -rf udemy-review.avsc
rm: cannot remove 'udemy-review.avsc': Permission denied
```

Comment: `sudo fuser -v -m udemy-review.avsc` will tell you if the file is locked by a process.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful command, I found out it's WSL's init()/bash shell lock the file. After closing those consoles the problem is gone.

Answer (score 6):

To delete a file you don't need write permission for the file but write and execute permissions for the folder(directory) the file is in.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I took another look, the hosting folder was set properly.

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed that I had to come all the way to stackoverflow to figure this out.